# How to replace all punctuation marks in a string except for square brackets and backslashes?

Tags: python

For example, if I have

```
'address": [{"type": null, "value": "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway\nMountain View\nCA\n94043\nUnited States"}]',
```

I want it to be like this

```
'address [type null value 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway\nMountain View\nCA\n94043\nUnited States]'
```

Comment: Have you done any research whatsoever? SO should be your last resort, not your first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use replace as the following:

```
my_str = 'define_your_string_here'
to_be_replaced = [':','\"','{','}']
for rep in to_be_replaced:
    my_str = my_str.replace(rep, '')
```

Comment: Such elegance :)

Comment: Elegance is before anything else ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's String's [`replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) method.

```
>>> YourString = 'address": [{"type": null, "value": "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway\nMountain View\nCA\n94043\nUnited States"}]'
>>> YourString.replace('"', '').replace('{', '').replace('}', '').replace(':', '').replace(',', '')
'address [type null value 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway\nMountain View\nCA\n94043\nUnited States]'
```